# HQL DISTINCT doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, dao

I searched throughout the forum; almost every answer comes to this but didn't help.
I have the below query in my DAO but it doesn't work and I don't understand why?

Here's my complete method:

```
public List<RwTac> findAll(){
        String sql = "select distinct v from RwTac v " +
                     "order by v.vendor" ;
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
        return query.list();
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a column called v in the RwTac table?

Comment: no; query normally works and brings me vendor called as "v" here but they're not unique...

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` and `hashCode` in your entities?

Comment: renaming alias didn't help. @SJuan76 no, I didn't does it help?

Comment: `DISTINCT` will give you unique results by one of two ways: by executing the `DISTINCT`in the SQL or by checking the results and erasing duplicates. I do not know for sure how hibernate does it, but I do not think it is the first way since then you would not have this trouble. If it is the second one then you need `equals()` and `hashCode()` so Hibernate can decide which are the duplicates.

Comment: I just implemented equals() and hashCode() still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which result you want to have.

In your HQL select

```
"select distinct v from RwTac v order by v.vendor"
```

you'll get all rows which differ in at least one column - and in most cases this will be all rows of the table (except if your table does not have a unique key and it has complete doubles).

If you want to have a list of the vendors, no vendor twice in the list, then you need this select

```
"select distinct v.vendor from RwTac v order by v.vendor"
```